# call an azure functions from a web app using msal on-behalf

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-ad-msal

I'm developing an application that have a web front and an azure function in the backend. I have protect the azure function using easyauth. The application is multitenant and i want to call the azure function on-behalf of authenticated user on the web. I want to use MSAL. I obtain a token on be-half of the user, i check it with jwt.io and all the informations are correct, scope is ok but when i call the function adding the Authentication token "Bearer:xxxxxxxxxxx" i obtain a 401. Seems to me that the problem is on the Function side: same parameter, compatibility with MSAL...
 Is there a racomandated architecture for this scenario. I found many but nothing specific about Azure Functions, EasyAuth, on-behalf msal token

Comment: During the build 2019 was clear that msal is the future and strong part of Microsoft strategy. At the same time there where some announcement about Azure Functions but nothing about authentication. I think that easyauth is not a solutions for pro apis and azure functions should provide the best in class approach to auth. So when msal will be supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, we cannot use v2 endpoint(msal) to authenticate Azure function in Azure Portal for now.

Currently, authentication providers in Azure Web App service contain Azure Active Directory and it use v1 ednpoint to redirect.

You can find more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it'd meet all your requirements, but you could front the web app with [API management using OAuth2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) and then set headers to appropriate values and redirect to an HTTP Trigger for your function [using one of the AuthorizationLevel options available](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-authentication-to-your-http-triggered-azure).

Sounds like EasyAuth is on people's minds already and there may be a solution for you somewhere in the comments on the [github ticket](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/33).